# Good patterns to log inside @Transactional method

Tags: spring, logging, transactions

I usually have **@Transactional** method (application layer) which calls some logic on domain layer.

Now, if I log the actions taken inside this method (layer) or inside domain layer, and I do it this way since I have all the details about the operation here, I end up with logs which are not accurate, since, even if transaction was rolled back and actions taken were not successful actually, logs contain "action taken" entries. Is this

Is there a good way to achieve this in Spring? Maybe some kind of transactional logger?

Comment: Take a loot at [`@TransactionalEventListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html).